# Why do power supplies get less efficient at high load?

Tags: power-supply, power, load, efficiency

Many PSUs follow the 80 PLUS standards, and it shows efficiency peaks at intermediate loads.

Power supplies are less efficient at low loads due to quiescent current. But why are they also less efficient at high loads?

Comment: Are you simply talking about consumer computer power supplies (80 Plus mark assumes that) or some other power supplies?

Comment: Can we have a datasheet link that shows the efficiency curve? (Add it into your question rather than in the comments.)

Comment: Depends on the power supply most DC to DC converters get more efficient with more power then less efficient

Answer (score 13):

At higher loads conduction losses get higher.  Power increases as the square of current, so the copper traces, on resistances of the FETs, and resistance of the inductors will contribute to higher losses at high load.

Depending on the topology, there could be other elements of the design that have higher loss with load, like possibly core losses for example, but conduction losses usually dominate at high load.

Comment: This; switching losses generally track (i.e. proportionally) with load current as well.

Comment: Why is that, if the switching frequency is constant?

Comment: @SteveSh Because the switching losses are due to there being voltage across the switch while it's carrying current.  So the power increases with the current.  It's more linear than the conduction losses which increase with current squared.

Comment: @John D - Some might characterize that as an ohmic loss.  Switching losses might be considered those that occur during turn on/turn off times of the switching devices, which is usually when the dissipation in those devices is the greatest.

Comment: @SteveSh That’s what I was trying (and failing) to say, the transition period when the switch is in the linear region and has significant voltage across it AND current through it at the same time.  There’s also of course gate drive losses that are not dependent on load current.  Reverse recovery and dead time diode conduction losses can be load dependent too.

Comment: At higher powers, inductors start reaching their current saturation limit and start passing extra current causing increased dissipation instead of storing energy. Also, many inductors start decreasing in inductance at higher currents, or when they heat up.

Answer (score 2):

> *Power supplies are less efficient at low loads due to quiescent
> current. But why are they also less efficient at high loads?*

If you go to the opposite extreme of a low load you have a short-circuit load and, there can be no energy delivered to a short circuit but, the power supply is still consuming energy hence, it's efficiency is zero. So, open-circuit or short-circuit, the efficiency of any power supply is zero. Somewhere in the middle is peak efficiency: -

[image]

Modified image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125836/help-compare-my-results-to-the-maximum-power-transfer-theorem-and-explain-using). You can also plot the maximum power transfer curve for fairly simple power supplies such as an ideal voltage source in series with a current limiting resistor: -

[image]

This is an example of a 10 volt source in series with a 10 Ω limiting resistor. A variable load is added to the output and, you can see that maximum power is transferred to the load at 0.5 amps or, when the source resistance equals the load resistance.

And, if you plotted efficiency of this simple power supply (whilst assuming a background quiescent power draw of 0.1 watts) you would get this: -

[image]

Comment: But isn't the smallest relevant load that which just barely allows the power supply to keep it's output voltage? I.e., we shouldn't really be worried too much about the efficiency at loads that are so small that the regulator can't regulate anymore, and hence the limit $R_L -> 0$ isn't the right one to look at?

Comment: @Timo this is a theoretical question about power transfer. Sure, any real-world power supply has to cope with what is thrown at it (within reason).